# Kubuntu 15.04 KDE 15.08 language problem

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, language-support, kde5

Having Kubuntu 15.4 installed (vivid).

I just switched from from kubuntu-ppa-backports (KDE 15.04) to kubuntu ci ppa (KDE 15.08.2) https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ci/+archive/ubuntu/stable.

Everything is great but I can't get my language pack (german) installed via systemsettings / regional settings.

Since aptitude(apt-get) still offers the old kde-l10n-de_15.04.x.deb and the ppa doesn't have any lang.packs I manually installed the kde-l10n-de_15.08.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb which is for wiley but shouldn't hurt the vivid.

So kde-l10n-de and language-pack-kde-de are installed, what can I do add my language to kde 15.08.2. It's still only showing American English in the lang. selection.

Any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staging depots (as CI) are not meant for every day use in a stable production environment.

Wonder who gave the recommondation w/o a warning?

The content of CI-stable will after a prolonged testing period merge to the backports-ppa, by then the language files will go into production and missing terms will be added by the official team.

Further reading -> http://wire.kubuntu.org/
-> http://wire.kubuntu.org/?p=424
... 
About CI-staging: scarlettgatelyclark.com/2015/kubuntu-kde-applications-15-08-3-bugfix-release-is-ready-for-testing/

extracted content: "... Once this has been tested and placed in Wily backports, I will backport it to Vivid."

edited 17.11. 3:46

Thanks to your question a comment was now added to the ppa-description:
*Direct landing PPA - highly fluctuating DO NOT USE THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING. ppa:kubuntu-ci/stable-daily is much nicer*

You should also pin kde-l10n-de back to 15.04.xx version (with backports-ppa activated in your case), otherwise you won't receive updates of this package. If you are not familiar with this process, you find it well described in: (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apt-Pinning) 
If you don't get along by yourself - they have a forum to ask. Their motto is: "Fragen ist menschlich"

Comment: Thanks, good to know. KDE 15.08 from CI is running better than 15.04 from backports.